# What do the different parts of Chrome dev tools url mean?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

If I run a Node.js application using the new `--inspect` flag, I get a url for debugging such as:

> chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:3000/5baf857d-5514-4f27-8410-b2ab94aed057

What do the different parts of this url mean, and how are they made up? It's pretty obvious what the human-readable words mean, but what is of special interest to me is:

- What does `@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980` mean?
- What does `5baf857d-5514-4f27-8410-b2ab94aed057` refer to?

Unfortunately, I do not really now how to search for this on the web, so any hint or help would be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: File hash and security hash. What now?

Comment: And how are they made up? The hash of what file is calculated? How does the security hash gets calculated? (I slightly updated my question)

Comment: The *Chromium* [source code for the devtools is available](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/+/master). That code might help you out.